# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. the authentication header

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sharepoint, ssl

I'm trying to call a webservice from our office sharepoint. It works when I call it from our testing project and I can access the url and retrieve information through the browser but when I call it through a webservice I get the following error:

System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=

When we log into sharepoint we use our windows credentials to login automatically.

My web config looks like this within :

```
<binding name="ListsSoap" closetimeout="00:01:00" opentimeout="00:01:00" receivetimeout="00:10:00"
    sendtimeout="00:01:00" allowcookies="false" bypassproxyonlocal="false" hostnamecomparisonmode="StrongWildcard"
    maxbuffersize="65536" maxbufferpoolsize="524288" maxreceivedmessagesize="65536"
    messageencoding="Text" textencoding="utf-8" transfermode="Buffered" usedefaultwebproxy="true">

  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
     maxArrayLength="16384"
                       maxBytesPerRead="4096"
    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
    <message
    clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

The url uses SSL (i.e. https://blahblah.com.sharepoint.emea.microsoftonline.com/Lists/....)

I've used almost every combination there is: transport with ntlm, TransportWithMessageCredential with basic etc and I either get the error message that it's expecting http and it get's https.

Thanks for the help

E

Comment: I would guess that Sharepoint is passing the credentials the Sharepoint application is running as on the Sharepoint server and not the user that is logged in. Can you see the error in the event viewer? That might have the error "user '' does not have permission..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client and server is using different authentication scheme. The server uses 'Basic Authentication' while your client uses 'Negotiate' which I guess is Windows Authentication.